# Text & Image rendering In UITableviewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

May be It's not too late to me to know about rendering of Images or Text in the cell.

I am bit confused about this.
If we have text & image to be shown in cell. Which one first renders. The TEXT or the IMAGE ?.
If the answer not **asynchronously**. Please give me proper explanation so that it will also helps others how are in my stage. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you care?  It shouldn't matter. it's not rendering in real time anyway.  You call the drawing routines, then it's drawn when it falls out of your code. Stock, default iOS cells come with one image and some lines of text in various flavors.  If you have anything more exciting then that, then use a custom UITableViewCell class to form your cells, and life will be a lot easier.